# ¿como modificar action form? Django

Tags: html, jquery, python, python-3.x, django

Tengo este `form` en un template:

```
<form method='POST' action='{% url "proceso-compra" object.slug %}'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <span>TALLA </span>
                <select name="talla" id='id_talla'>
                  {% for s in stock %}
                     {% if s.cantidad != 0 %}
                        <option value="{{s.id}}"> {{s.talla}} (uds. {{s.cantidad}})</option>
                     {% endif %}
                 {% endfor %}
                </select>
    <button class="btn-lo-quiero"> LO QUIERO</button>
</form>
```

Mi problema es que quiero modificar el action de este formulario según la opción que seleccione y no sé exactamente como puedo hacerlo.

Comment: Cuando dices que quieres modificar el `action` a qué te refieres exactamente? Es decir, si escoge alguna opción debe ir a una página específica? Lo primero que te digo es que de ser así, no estás haciendo nada escalable, lo ideal sería resolverlo en un solo sitio, y segundo para lograr eso, necesitarías hacerlo con Javascript

Comment: podrias usar algo como esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388954/redirect-form-to-different-url-based-on-select-option-element

Comment: funciona, gracias.